# Python PXSSH GUI spawn on login failure

Tags: python, user-interface, ssh, pexpect

I can't stop the GUI from spawning when a login failure occurs.

simple example that fails and spawns a GUI.

```
>>> import pxssh 
>>> 
>>> ssh = pxssh.pxssh()
>>> ssh.force_password = True
>>> ssh.login('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'falsePW')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pxssh.py", line 226, in login
    raise ExceptionPxssh ('password refused')
pxssh.ExceptionPxssh: password refused
>>>
```

I have tried disabling x11 forwarding in these files, nothing changed.

`/etc/ssh/ssh_config`
`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

I have also tried going into the pxssh module and where it sets the ssh options I set the flag `-x  Disables X11 forwarding.` still no change.

I am running cinnamon on Linux Mint, the pxssh docs said some x display managers will start up a GUI. To solve this is says to remove all ssh-agents, which I have also tried to no avail.

Comment: I had same problem. But it turns out that the password I provided was wrong.

Comment: I was trying to remove a unix gui error upon an invalid password. I wanted my application to provide a page upon and expected invaild login error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tampering with the `pxssh.py` module I found a solution thats very simple.

inside the pxssh.py module: `sudo nano /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pxssh.py`

Location Update: `sudo nano /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/pxssh.py`

```
class pxssh(spawn)

    def _init__( parameters )

        # change these variables to shown value
        self.force_password = True   
        self.auto_prompt_reset = False

    # next under the login function
    def login( parameters )
        # set the -x flag: disables x11 forwarding (removing GUI)
        ssh_options = '-q -x'
```