# Python 2.6 pxssh Password GUI spawned on login failure

Tags: python, linux, ssh, openssh, suse

Before I get into the details, I have already attempted the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832740/python-pxssh-gui-spawn-on-login-failure) with no success.

I am trying to use the pxssh module within pexpect to SSH to a remote system and collect the uptime data.  However, whenever I enter the incorrect password, the script generates a GUI password prompt for openSSH.

The script will query a large number of systems and write the output to a log, so I want it to just write a note in the log whenever the SSH connection fails; I don't want it to ever pop up a window.

Here is the current code of the function:

```
def getUptime(ipAddr, passwd):
    try:
        os.unsetenv('SSH_ASKPASS')
        ssh = px.pxssh.pxssh()
        ssh.options={"NumberOfPasswordPrompts":"1"}
        ssh.force_password=True
        ssh.options = {'RequestTTY':'Force'}
        ssh.login(ipAddr,"root",passwd,auto_prompt_reset=False)
        ssh.sendline("uptime")
        ssh.prompt()
        uptime = ssh.before.split()
        ssh.logout()
        uptime = ' '.join(uptime[uptime.index('up'):]).split(',')[0].strip('up')
        return(uptime)
    except(px.pxssh.ExceptionPxssh):
        return("SSH connection failed; double-check the password")
```

I apologize if there are typos in that code, I had to re-type it by hand since Virtualbox is not letting me copy and paste from my development environment (SLES 11 x64, if that matters), even with bidirectional clipboard enabled.

I have tried the following steps (some of which are visible above):

1. Set `ssh.force_password=True`
2. Set `ssh.options = {'RequestTTY':'Force'}` (This should be equivalent to using "-t" in the SSH CLI argument, if I understand the openSSH documentation)
3. Set `auto_prompt_reset=False`
4. Edit pxssh.py to set "ssh_options" from '' to '-t -x' (I tried each option separately, then both together).
5. Manually unset SSH_ASKPASS in the shell before running the script.
6. Unset SSH_ASKPASS with `os.unsetenv()` immediately before invoking pxssh within the script.
7. Set the "NumberOfPasswordPrompts" option to "1".

The observed behavior when it gets an incorrect password is that it will print "SSH connection failed..." as expected, but it will also popup the openSSH password window.

None of those listed steps has had any noticeable effect on the script's performance whatsoever, and most of my Google searches on this issue point back to that linked question.  If anyone has any idea of how I can possibly 100% suppress that password window, I would very much appreciate the assistance.

Thank you all in advance for your advice.

**Potential Solution**
I've found that I can keep the window from popping up by taking the following steps:

1. In pxssh.py change ssh_options from `''` to `"-o 'NumberOfPasswordPrompts=1'"`
2. In my script, catch `pexpect.EOF` along with `pexpect.pxssh.ExceptionPxssh` to determine when a password has failed.

I'm not accepting this as an answer just yet because it seems like a very poor solution to me, particularly editing pxssh.py.  I attempted to set the NumberOfPasswordPrompts option within my script, but it has no effect, so I must have the incorrect syntax.

Comment: Yes I agree with you that modifying the pxssh module is a bad fix. I never got any help with this problem. I hope you have better luck. Maybe make a post about how to monkey patch pxssh. I've heard the term being thrown around for problems like these recently. Although I haven't taken the time to actually find out what it is.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to update pxssh.py at all. Instead:

```
ssh = px.pxssh.pxssh()
ssh.force_password = True
ssh.SSH_OPTS = "-o 'NumberOfPasswordPrompts=1'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem quite a while ago, see if this helps. [Python PXSSH GUI spawn on login failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832740/python-pxssh-gui-spawn-on-login-failure)

If not then trying opening the pxsssh module in you python library. If I remember correctly theres an issue that's explained in the `__init__` where all you need to do is comment a line and uncomment a line.

#### Edit:

In the pexpect package theres the pxssh.py file, open it up and look at line `115` there should be your fix. Heres what your looking for

#### path: `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/pxssh.py`

```
# Comment this line
self.SSH_OPTS = ("-o'RSAAuthentication=no'"
        + " -o 'PubkeyAuthentication=no'")


# Disabling host key checking, makes you vulnerable to MITM attacks.
#                + " -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no'"
#                + " -o 'UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null' ")
# Disabling X11 forwarding gets rid of the annoying SSH_ASKPASS from
# displaying a GUI password dialog. I have not figured out how to
# disable only SSH_ASKPASS without also disabling X11 forwarding.
# Unsetting SSH_ASKPASS on the remote side doesn't disable it! Annoying!

# UNCOMMENT THE LINE BELOW 
#self.SSH_OPTS = "-x -o'RSAAuthentication=no' -o 'PubkeyAuthentication=no'"
self.force_password = False
self.auto_prompt_reset = True
```

I haven't used the pxssh module in quite sometime. But I think you can find away to override the SSH_OPTS so that you don't need to physically modify the module.